# snmpd on Synology DSM6 cannot be joined anymore : snmpget: Timeout (Sub-id not found: (top) -> sysName)

Tags: snmp, synology-diskstation, snmpwalk

The `snmp` service on a Synology DSM6 cannot be joined anymore :

```shell
SynoServer $ snmpwalk -v3 -A $MDP_SNMP -l authNoPriv -u svc_snmp localhost system | grep sysName.0
snmpwalk: Timeout (Sub-id not found: (top) -> system)
```

So I restarted the `snmp` service on the Synology DSM6 but that didn't solve the problem :

```shell
SynoServer $ sudo synoservice --restart snmp
SynoServer $ sudo synoservice --status snmp
Service [snmp] status=[enable]
required upstart job:
        [snmpd] is start.
=======================================
SynoServer $ netstat -4nul | grep :161
udp     4608      0 0.0.0.0:161             0.0.0.0:*
SynoServer $ ps -fC snmpd
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      9139     1  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/snmpd -fLn -c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf -p /var/run/snmpd.pid udp:161,udp6:161,tcp:161,tcp6:161
SynoServer $
```

I have no clue where the `snmp` logs are on this device.

EDIT0 : The `snmp` service seems instable here :

```shell
SynoServer $ snmpwalk -v3 -A $MDP_SNMP -l authNoPriv -u svc_snmp localhost system | grep sysName.0
snmpwalk: Timeout (Sub-id not found: (top) -> system)
SynoServer $ snmpwalk -v3 -A $MDP_SNMP -l authNoPriv -u svc_snmp localhost system | grep sysName.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: PAR-SYN01
SynoServer $ snmpwalk -v3 -A $MDP_SNMP -l authNoPriv -u svc_snmp localhost system | grep sysName.0
snmpwalk: Timeout (Sub-id not found: (top) -> system)
SynoServer $
```

Can you help me ?